# how to echo an associative array in a page?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am just starting learning codes and am writing some codes to echo an array and it give me this two errors:

> Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ogmt\rest_server_api.php on line 70
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ogmt\rest_server_api.php on line 71..

HOW CAN I SOLVE THIS? This is my code:

```
    if($Result1){
      // script to get business no, amount & merchant id,output to merchant page
      $query="SELECT * FROM customer_order WHERE order_time=(SELECT max(order_time)from customer_order)";
      $result=mysql_query($query);
      while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $amount=$row['amount'];
          $id=$row['merchant_id'];
          $payment_mode=$row['mobile_service'];
          switch($payment_mode){               
           case 'TIGO-PESA':
            $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobile_client WHERE mobile_service='TIGO-PESA'");
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){ 
                 $data=array(
                   'Business no'=>$row1['business_no'],
                   'Payment Mode'=>$payment_mode,
                   'Total Amount Tsh'=>$amount,
                   'Merchant ID'=>$id
                   );
                   }break;
                        
            case 'M-PESA':
            $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobile_client WHERE mobile_service='M-PESA'");
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){ 
                 $data=array(
                   'Business no'=>$row1['business_no'],
                   'Payment Mode'=>$payment_mode,
                   'Total Amount Tsh'=>$amount,
                   'Merchant ID'=>$id
                   );
                   }break;
            case 'AIRTEL-MONEY':
            $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobile_client WHERE mobile_service='AIRTEL-MONEY'");
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){ 
                 $data=array(
                   'Business no'=>$row1['business_no'],
                   'Payment Mode'=>$payment_mode,
                   'Total Amount Tsh'=>$amount,
                   'Merchant ID'=>$id
                    );
                   }break;
                        
           // default:
           $data=array('error'=>"no payment mode selected");        
        }
           $response=array('details'=>$data);
        }
    }
     
     else{
          $response=array('details'=>"query failed!");
          }
         
      }
 //print output to merchant page to complete payment
 $keys = array_keys($data);
  foreach($response['details'] as $keys=>$value){
       echo "$keys: $value</br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($data);`

Comment: Well, $data happens to be null

Comment: I recommend you to join your tables via SQL. Then you save additional DB work and you have less duplicate code

Answer (score 1):

Wrap this code

```
<?php 
if(isset($response['details']) && is_array($response['details'])){
   foreach($response['details'] as $keys=>$value){
       echo "$keys: $value</br>";
   }
}else{
   echo "Array is empty";
}
?>
```

Comment: I use your code and the the error is no more.. but this time it does not print anything

Comment: But my is not supposed to be empty!! I need to retrieve some details from database

Comment: But my array is not supposed to be empty!! I need to retrieve some details from database

Answer (score 1):

you can not echo an array, you can try either `var_dump($data);` or `print_r($data)`

Also you can use `implode("", $_POST[$data]);` ,that is closer to echo.

Answer (score 0):

Try these tools if you see them being quite big arrays..
http://krumo.sourceforge.net/

Once loaded you can do a simple call like this in your PHP code. Download the script from the site and place it into your site and call it using the require() function

```
require 'class.krumo.php';
krumo($your_array); // will output your array :)
```

Comment: how can i use krumo tools?

Comment: The problem is resolved, Ts seems there was an error in my query. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Just use print_r function to view the contents. [**By the way you had an extra brace** (removed it)]

```
    <?php
if($Result1){
    // script to get business no, amount & merchant id,output to merchant page
    $query="SELECT * FROM customer_order WHERE order_time=(SELECT max(order_time)from customer_order)";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $amount=$row['amount'];
        $id=$row['merchant_id'];
        $payment_mode=$row['mobile_service'];
        switch($payment_mode){
            case 'TIGO-PESA':
                $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobile_client WHERE mobile_service='TIGO-PESA'");
                while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
                    $data=array(
                        'Business no'=>$row1['business_no'],
                        'Payment Mode'=>$payment_mode,
                        'Total Amount Tsh'=>$amount,
                        'Merchant ID'=>$id
                    );
                }
                break;

            case 'M-PESA':
                $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobile_client WHERE mobile_service='M-PESA'");
                while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
                    $data=array(
                        'Business no'=>$row1['business_no'],
                        'Payment Mode'=>$payment_mode,
                        'Total Amount Tsh'=>$amount,
                        'Merchant ID'=>$id
                    );
                }break;
            case 'AIRTEL-MONEY':
                $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobile_client WHERE mobile_service='AIRTEL-MONEY'");
                while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
                    $data=array(
                        'Business no'=>$row1['business_no'],
                        'Payment Mode'=>$payment_mode,
                        'Total Amount Tsh'=>$amount,
                        'Merchant ID'=>$id
                    );
                }break;

             default:
                 $data=array('error'=>"no payment mode selected");
                break;

        }
        $response=array('details'=>$data);
    }
}

else{
    $response=array('details'=>"query failed!");

}
//print output to merchant page to complete payment
print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: It still prints nothing

Comment: @maro, sorry it should be `print_r($response);` i have modified the code

Comment: Now it prints: Array ( [details] => )

Comment: Seems like your switch statement fails. Is your query executing properly ?

Comment: I have tried the code and it gives this output:Array ( [details] => Array ( [error] => no payment mode selected ) )

Comment: It is evident that `$payment_mode=$row['mobile_service'];` is returning nothing or empty.  Can you run the query manually and check the results on mysql and let me know ?

Comment: The problem is resolved, Ts seems there was an error in my query. Thank you guys